# Bounding projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-geometry, projective-space, big-picture, cobordism

For which $n$ does there exist a (topological, smooth, PL, complex) manifold $M^n$ such that $\partial M = \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^m$. Obvously, $m = n -1 $ (at least an in the real case). There are a couple of questions:

- Does there always exist a bounding projective space. And if not, what are the demands on your $M^n$ to have a bounding projective space (that is, apart from the obvious ones) ?
- When does non-orientability of the bounding projective space implies non-orientability of the $M^n$ (Obviously, when $\partial M^{2n+1}=\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^{2n}$, then the boundary is non-orientable) ?
- When does a complex projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ bounds ? And is there any "aftereffect" (i.e. are there some specific properties that such a (probably smooth) $2n-1$-manifold has because of the complex structure of the bounding $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$) visible in the manifold that it bounds because of the complex structure of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ ?
- Does the fake complex projective plane bounds anything ?

I know this is a multitude of questions spanning probably a multitude of disciplines.

Comment: related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8829/what-manifolds-are-bounded-by-rpodd

Comment: (relevant concepts are _cobordism_ and _characteristic numbers_)

Comment: Intuitively, boundaries have to be oriented... but I'm not seeing an obvious proof, so perhaps this is not true. What is obvious, though, is that there is a manifold with boundary $\mathbb{RP}^1$, since $\mathbb{RP}^1$ is a circle. I suspect $\mathbb{RP}^3$ might also be a boundary, since it is homeomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

Comment: @Zhen: apparently the Klein bottle is a boundary.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thanks. I was looking for a counterexample but apparently I was using the wrong keywords. That's very interesting...

Comment: ...and also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14698/what-manifold-has-mathbbhpodd-as-a-boundary

Comment: @Zhen:  A product of manifolds $M_1\times M_2$ is orientable iff both factors are.  On the other hand, the product of a manifold which bounds with anything bounds.  Thus, if say $M_1$ bounds and either of $M_1$ or $M_2$ is nonorientable, then $M_1\times M_2$ is nonorientable and bounds.  For a concrete example, $S^1\times\mathbb{R}P^2$ bounds $D^2\times\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: So a better question whould be: when you call a manifold irreucible (I am certainly this is not the right term here) if from $M_1 \times M_2$ it follows that either $M_1$ or $M_2$ is empty, look for irreducible bounding $M^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was alluded to in the mathoverflow post Grigory posted, $\mathbb R P^n$ is a boundary if and only if $n$ is odd.  You can see that $\mathbb R P^{2n}$ cannot be a boundary by using Stiefel-Whitney numbers; for a manifold to be a boundary you need all its Stiefel-Whitney numbers to vanish, which is the case for only the odd projective spaces.

A good reference for this is p. 51-53 of Milnor and Stasheff's ``Characteristic Classes."

Comment: I know this works in the smooth category, but what about in the other categories the OP mentions?

Comment: @Jason AFAIR, $w_n$ of a (PL) manifold can be defined just as the sum of all simplices of (co)dimension n — so S-W numbers seem to give an obstruction to cobordism in PL category as well.

Comment: ...so MPL=MO. And MTop=MO in dim≠4 (by some surgery theory, AFAIK)...